# React native dropdown pciker fetch from api

Tags: react-native

Hi everyone I'm trying to use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker) .it work fine with static values but my values comes form api.

```
this.state={  country: 'uk',}
 <DropDownPicker
                  items={[
                    {
                      label: 'USA',
                      value: 'usa',

                      
                    },
                    {
                      label: 'UK',
                      value: 'uk',
                    },
                    {
                      label: 'France',
                      value: 'france',
                    },
                  ]}
                  searchable={true}
                  defaultValue={this.state.country}
                  containerStyle={{height: 40}}
                  style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa', color: 'black'}}
                  itemStyle={{
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  }}
                  dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
                  onChangeItem={(item) =>
                    this.setState({
                      country: item.value,
                    })
                  }
                />
```

its like that . It accepts `*label*` and `value` type but api return it with diffrent

values like

`value as COUNTRY_ID`

`label as COUNTRY`

How can i fill the dropdown with is data, should i map it or another way. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array like this

```
var pickerItems = []

listFromApi.forEach(item => {
            pickerItems.push({
                      label: item.countryName,
                      value: item.countryId,
              })
        });
```

Or you can use the map function

```
     <DropDownPicker
           items={listFromApi.map((item) => {
                      return {label: item.countryName,
                              value: item.countryId}
                         })}
     />
```

Comment: Well it works thank you but is this the exact way

Comment: You can use the map. which I know this pickerview only accepts the object of label and value.